# Mips Runtime exception at 0x00400258: address out of range 0x00000068

Tags: assembly, mips, procedure, mars-simulator

I am trying to implement a `word occurance counter in a string program` in mips and whenever I call the strcmp function I get the error `Runtime exception at 0x00400258: address out of range 0x00000068` I really don't understand why as I am still new to mips below I will provide the c code and the full mips code in order to be as simple as posible for the viewer .

expected input string ex: hello world hello

expected output hello  - 2

```
            world  - 1
```

`the strcmp function`

```
strcmp:
 addi $sp,$sp,-4
 sw $ra 0($sp)
 
 addi $t0,$0,0       
 add $t1,$0,$a2       # pass argument a2 to $t1
 add $t2,$0,$a3       # pass argument a3 to $t2
 
 L6: 
 lb $t3,($t1)  #load a byte from each string
 lb $t4,($t2)
 beqz $t3,T4Check #str1 end
 beqz $t4,missmatch
 subu $t5,$t3,$t4  #compare two bytes
 bnez $t5,missmatch
 addi $t1,$t1,1  #t1 points to the next byte of str1
 addi $t2,$t2,1
 j L6
 
 missmatch: 
 addi $v0,$0,1
 j finish2
 T4Check:
 bnez $t4,missmatch
 addi $v0,$0,0     
 finish2:
 lw $ra,0($sp)        # restore old $sp
 addi $sp,$sp,4 
 jr $ra
```

`the function call part`

```
Else:      
         add $t8,$t2,$s7         # add base ptr1 to offset j
         lb $a2,($t8)            # $a2 = ptr1[j]
         add $t6,$t0,$s6         # add base p to offset i
         lb $a3,($t6)            # $a3 = p[i]
         jal strcmp              # jump strcmp
```

`My full C code`

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 int my_strcmp(char *strg1, char *strg2){

while( ( *strg1 != '\0' && *strg2 != '\0' ) && *strg1 == *strg2 )
{
    strg1++;
    strg2++;
}

if(*strg1 == *strg2)
{
    return 0; // strings are identical
}

else
{
    return *strg1 - *strg2;
}
}

void new_strcpy(char x[],char y[]){
int i=0;
while((x[i]=y[i])!=0){
    i++;
}
}

int my_strlen(char str[]){
int len=0,i=0;
while(str[i]!='\0'){
    i++;
    len++;
}
return len;
}

void word_statistics(char str[]){
int count = 0, c = 0, i, j = 0, k, space = 0;
char p[100][100],ptr1[100][100];


printf("string length is %d\n", my_strlen(str));
i=0;
while(i<my_strlen(str))
{
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        space++;
    }
    i++;
}
i=0;
j=0;
k=0;
while(j < my_strlen(str))
{
    if (str[j] == ' ')
    {
        p[i][k] = '\0';
        i++;
        k = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        p[i][k++] = str[j];
    }
    j++;
}

k=0;
i=0;
while(i <= space)
{   j=0;
    while(j <= space)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            j++;
            new_strcpy(ptr1[k], p[i]);
            k++;
            count++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (my_strcmp(ptr1[j], p[i]) != 0){
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            else{
                j++;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    i++;
}
printf("%d",count);
i=0;
while(i < count)
{
    j=0;
    while(j <= space)
    {
        if (my_strcmp(ptr1[i], p[j]) == 0)
            c++;
        j++;
    }
    printf("  %s       :   %d \n", ptr1[i], c);
    c = 0;
    i++;
  }
}

int main(){
char str[100];

printf("Enter the string\n");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", str);
word_statistics(str);
return 0;
}
```

`My full mips code`

```
.data
 msg: .asciiz "Enter a string \n"
 str: .space 30       # get the paragraph from the user
 ptr1 : .space 400     #ptr1[20][20]
 p: .space 400        #p[20][20]
    
 
 stringlen: .asciiz "String length is "
 blankSpace: .ascii  " "
 next: .asciiz "\n Next while"
.text

main:
 jal word_stat
 
word_stat:
 addi $sp,$sp,-4
 sw $ra 0($sp)

 li $v0,4     
 la $a0,msg   
 syscall              # printing the message to the user
 
 li $v0,8
 la $a0,str
 li $a1,30
 syscall              # getting a paragraph from the user
 
 li $v0,4
 la $a0,stringlen     #"String length is "
 syscall
 la $a0,str
 jal strlen
 addi $a0,$v0,0
 addi $s3,$a0,0      #strlen value   $s3
 li $v0,1
 syscall              # calling the strlen function to count the string length
 
 la $a3,blankSpace
 lb $s4,0($a3)      # $s4 =blankspace
 
 addi $s2,$0,0     # space =0
 addi $t0,$0,0     # i=0
 la $a1,str
 
 while1: 
     slt $t5,$t0,$s3   #set $t5=1 if i < strlength
     beq $t5,$0,L5     #if i>strlength
     add $t6,$a1,$t0   # $a0 = str[]
     lbu $t6,0($t6)    # str[i]
     beq $t6,$s4,L2    #if str[i]==' ' branch 
     L3:     
     addi $t0,$t0,1    # i++
     j while1
 
     L2:    
     addi $s2,$s2,1    # space ++ if str[i]==' '
     j L3             

     L5:     
     la,$a2,p       
     
     la $s5,str      # address start of str
     la $s6,p        # address start of p
     la $s7,ptr1     # address start of ptrl
     li $t9,20       # width =20
     li $t0,0        # i=0
     li $t2,0        # j=0
     li $t3,0        # k=0
  
  
 WHILE:
  bge $t2,$s3,End_While   # branch if j<=strlength
  add $t5,$t2,$s5
  lb $t7,($t5)           # $t7 = str[j]
  beq $t7,$s4,L           # if str[j]== ' ' branch L
  
  mul $t8,$t9,$t0         # width *i
  add $t8,$t8,$t3         # width * i+k
  add $t8,$t8,$s6         # base array (width *i+k)
  sb $t7,($t8)            # p[i][k++]=str[j]
  addi $t3,$t3,1          # k++
  
  L10: 
  addi $t2,$t2,1          # j++
  j WHILE
  
 L:  
  mul $t8,$t9,$t0         # array width * i 
  add $t8,$t8,$t3         # width * i+k
  add $t8,$t8,$s6         # base array +(width * i+k)  
  sb $zero,($t8)            # p[i][k++]='\0'
  addi $t0,$t0,1          # i++
  addi $t3,$zero,0        # k=0
  j L10           
End_While:
     
         li $t0,0     # i=0
         li $s0,0     # count=0
         li $t3,0     # k=0
         la $s6,p        # address start of p
         la $s7,ptr1     # address start of ptrl
  
       While2:
         slt $t4,$s2,$t0         # set $t4=1 if i>space
         beq $t4,1,End_While2    # End While loop if i>space
         addi $t2,$zero,0        # j=o
         
       While3:
         slt $t4,$s2,$t2         # set $t4=1 if j>space
         beq $t4,1,End_While3    # End while loop if j > space
         bne $t0,$t2,Else        # if i==j
         add $t8,$t3,$s7         # $t8 = add base address of ptr1 to offset k
         lb $a2,($t8)            # a2=ptr1[k]
         add $t6,$t0,$s6         # t6 = add base address of p to offset i
         lb $a3,($t6)            # a3 = p[i]
         jal strcpy              # jump strcmp function
         addi $t3,$t3,1          # k++
         addi $s0,$s0,1          # count ++
         addi $t2,$t2,1          # j++
         j End_While3            # break
         
      Else:      
         add $t8,$t2,$s7         # add base ptr1 to offset j
         lb $a2,($t8)            # $a2 = ptr1[j]
         add $t6,$t0,$s6         # add base p to offset i
         lb $a3,($t6)            # $a3 = p[i]
         jal strcmp              # jump strcmp
         move $t5,$v0            # move v0 value to t5
         beq $t5,$zero,Else2     # if strcmp(ptr1[j],p[i]!=0) branch else2
         addi $t2,$t2,1          # j++
         j While3                # continue
         
    Else2:
        addi $t2,$t2,1           # j++
        j End_While3             # break
                   
         
        j While3
  End_While3:
         addi $t0,$t0,1          # i++
         j While2
  End_While2:         

     li $t0,0   # i=0
     li $t3,0   # c=0
     
  While5:
     bge $t0,$s0,End_While5    # End loop if i >= count
     li $t2,0                  # j=0
   While6:
     slt $t5,$s2,$t2           # set t5=1 if j > space
     beq $t5,1,End_while6      # End loop if j > space
     add $t7,$t0,$s7           # base address of ptr1 + offset i
     lb $a2,($t7)              # a2 = ptr1[i]
     add $t8,$t2,$s6           # add base address p to offset j
     lb $a3,($t8)              # a3 =p[j]
     j strcmp
     move $t6,$v0              # return of function strcmp
     bne $t6,0,Loo             # if strcmp != 0
     addi $t3,$t3,1            # c++
    Loo:
     addi $t2,$t2,1            # j++
     j  While6
    End_while6:
     li $v0,4     
     move $a0,$a2
     syscall                  # print(ptr1[i]) word to count
     
     li $v0,1
     move $a0,$t3
     syscall                   # print c (word count number)
     
     addi $t3,$zero,0          # c=0
     addi $t0,$t0,1            # i++
     j While5
   End_While5:             
  
   li $v0,4     
   la $a0,next  
   syscall 
   
   li $v0 ,10
   syscall            # Exit terminating the program  

   lw $ra,0($sp)      # restore old $sp
   addi $sp,$sp,4 
   jr $ra


 strcmp:
 addi $sp,$sp,-4
 sw $ra 0($sp)
 
 addi $t0,$0,0       
 add $t1,$0,$a2       # pass argument a2 to $t1
 add $t2,$0,$a3       # pass argument a3 to $t2
 
 L6: 
 lb $t3,($t1)  #load a byte from each string
 lb $t4,($t2)
 beqz $t3,T4Check #str1 end
 beqz $t4,missmatch
 subu $t5,$t3,$t4  #compare two bytes
 bnez $t5,missmatch
 addi $t1,$t1,1  #t1 points to the next byte of str1
 addi $t2,$t2,1
 j L6
 
 missmatch: 
 addi $v0,$0,1
 j finish2
 T4Check:
 bnez $t4,missmatch
 addi $v0,$0,0     
 finish2:
 lw $ra,0($sp)        # restore old $sp
 addi $sp,$sp,4 
 jr $ra

 strcpy:
 addi $sp,$sp,-4
 sw $ra 0($sp)
 
 addi $t0,$0,0        # i=0
 L1:  
 add $t1,$s6,$t0      # address of y[i]
 lb $t2,($t1)         # load byte y[i] in $t2 
 add $t3,$s7,$t0      # similar address for x[i]
 sb $t2,($t3)        # store byte y[i] into x[i]
 addi $t0,$t0,1       # i++
 bne $t2,$0,L1        # if y[i]!=0 go to L1
 
 lw $t0,0($sp)        # restore old $s0
 addi $sp,$sp,4 
 jr $ra


 strlen:
 addi $sp,$sp,-4
 sw $ra,0($sp)
 addi $t0,$0,0      # i=0
 addi $t1,$0,0      # len=0
 l: 
 add $t2,$a0,$t0    # add base address to offset
 lbu $t3,0($t2)     # load base unsigned for char array
 beq $t3,$0,finish  # if value of array[i] = '\0'
 addi $t0,$t0,1     # i++
 addi $t1,$t1,1     # len++
 j l

finish:
 subi $t1,$t1,1
 add $v0,$t1,$0
 lw $ra,0($sp)        # restore old $sp
 addi $sp,$sp,4 
 jr $ra
```

Comment: You haven't told us which line of code address 0x00400258  corresponds to, but presumably it's a load/store instruction and the base address register contains a bad value. Set a breakpoint on the instruction at 0x00400258 and backtrack using Mars' "undo the last step" feature until you figure out how you ended up with that incorrect base address.

Comment: @Michael exactly it is in the load byte of as I specified in lb $t3,($t1) despite that t3 is empty and t1 is full I don't know whether I am passing the arguments in the right way or not as I added the base address ptr1[] to its offset i and loaded them to $a3 to be passed to the procedure and it is relly confusing for me

Comment: Its just a matter of basic debugging.  Are you getting the values you want when you want them?  Where does the program generate 0x68 generated?  What were you expecting instead?  Where does the code diverge from what you're expecting?

Comment: @ErikEidt I was expecting 0x68 as it means in this case the 'h' in hello what I don't understand is why the address is out of range

Comment: Looks like you're dereferencing something when you want to instead pass an address.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at some of your C code:

```
char p[100][100],ptr1[100][100];

...new_strcpy(ptr1[k], p[i])...

...my_strcmp(p[i],ptr1[j])...
```

These arrays are double dimensioned arrays.  But double dimensioned arrays, *while taking two `[]`'s to get to a character element, only require one **dereference to memory***.

`ptr1[k]` is not a dereference to memory — it is an address computation: `ptr1+k*100` and it changes the type to from `char [][]` to `char []`, but not a dereference in following sense: there is no memory access done by this, it is purely an in-CPU calculation.

`ptr1[k][i]` in assembly would do `ptr1+k*100+i`, then that address dereferenced — once — to get a character.

Thus, to pass `ptr1[k]` as a parameter, that is simply an address calculation — no dereference to memory involved.

Comment: I like this explanation, I always tried to explain it by saying "2D Arrays don't exist in hardware, you're doing ```base_ptr + (desired_row * rowlength * bytes_per_row) + (desired_column * bytes_per_column)``` " but I think your explanation is very good.